# How to send variables from a loop using javascript or jquery post method and receive using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want display all table values and then send and receive them on another php page using javascript post menthod but it seems my code is only able to send one item from the table list to another php page.

```
<form  class="commerce" id='commence'>
    <input type='text' id='shop' value='' class='form-wrapper'>
    <?php
    $check = "SELECT * FROM tbl_products ";
    $checks = mysqli_query($db, $check);
    while ($found = mysqli_fetch_array($checks)) {

        $id = $found['id'];
        $amount = $found['amount'];
        $price = $found['price'];
        echo"<input type='text' id='product' value='$id' class='form-wrapper'>
            <input type='text' id='stock' value='$amount' class='form-wrapper'>
            <input type='text' id='price' value='$price' class='form-wrapper'>";
    }
    ?>
    <button type='button' class='prisoner_entry '  >SAVE</button>
</form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on("click", ".prisoner_entry", function () {
        var fname = document.getElementById("shop").value;
        var product = document.getElementById("product").value;
        var stock = document.getElementById("stock").value;
        var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "data.php",
            data: {
                fullname: fname, productname: product, stocknumber: stock, itemprice: price},
            success: function (result) {
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['fullname'])){

              $fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["fullname"]);      
              $productname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["productname"]);  
              $stocknumber =mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["stocknumber"]);       
              $itemprice =mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["itemprice"]);      
              $rphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["rephone"]);     
                }   
?>
```

Comment: *"my code is only able to send one item from the table list to another php page"* - Is that (php) code included in the question now?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes

Comment: You're telling me that the file you are sending this all to, is what is declared in `url : "data.php",` and the form above with the inputs being echo'd in the `while` loop?

Comment: yes @FunkFortyNiner i think the probllems comes because the items from the loop dont have unique id so i need to send them as an array so i dont know how to dont know how to do that

Comment: Why do you use `mysqli_real_escape_string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating several elements with the same `id`.  Every `id` should be unique per page.  You should change them to `class` and retrieve i that manner.

PHP

```
echo "<input type='text' class='product form-wrapper' value='$id' />
...
```

JS

```
const form = document.querySelector('#commence');
const products = form.querySelectorAll('.product');
const stocks = form.querySelectorAll('.stock');
const prices = form.querySelectorAll('.price');
const shopItems = [];
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : "data.php",
    data : {
      productName: products[i].value,
      stockNumber: stocks[i].value,
      itemPrice: price[i].value
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: still sending one item from the list what i want to achieve is to send all items from the list item diplayed by the loop together with the shop name

Comment: @Pamzey The code above will make one call per item.  I'm not sure what format your endpoint is expecting.  If you need to group them, you should be able to modify the look to push all the data into a single object and then send that.

Comment: your code helped me to get the job done though i had to make some changes after studying it but what matters is achieving the objective so thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The way that I normally accomplish this is by appending the variables to the data of the ajax request like so:

```
data: $(this).serialize() + '&action=query',
```

the `$(this).serialize()` is the data from my web form

the `&` is how you differentiate between the variables you are passing.

the first part `action=` is the name that I will use to retrieve the data from the GET/POST variable in PHP.

and lastly, the `query` is the data that I am passing.

So, in your case you would do something like:

`data: someData + '&fname='+fname` .... and so on.

The most important thing to remember is that without a name, you will not be able to access the object in the GET/POST variables in your PHP.

Comment: i think what ur code is saying its the same as my code on this line data : {
                         fullname:fname,productname:product,stocknumber:stock,itemprice:price} am able to send to another page the only problem is that its only one item intead of more than one displayed from the loop

Comment: Show me the PHP on how you are accessing the data please